# IE Conditional Comment in XSLT 1.0 inside tag

Tags: html, xml, internet-explorer, xslt, conditional-statements

How to display title (**not as HTML comment**) for IE6 only, if this line of code
`<a title="" href="#">some text</a>` is in xsl file?

The options below don't work:

```
<a <![CDATA[[if IE 6]>title="hi"<![endif]]]> href="#">some text</a>


<a &lt;![if IE 6]&gt;"title="hi"&lt;![endif]&gt; href="#">some text</a>
```

I know this question supposed to be asked in 90's :)

Any other options?
Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you post the required result. That would be much more helpful in understanding your question than code that doesn't produce it.

Comment: @michael.hor257k The result is invalid xsl, the page doesn't display that file.

Comment: The page will display whatever **code** you tell it to. It does not validate.

Comment: [Conditional compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/121hztk3%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any conditional IE constructs other than those given in an HTML comment. To insert comments in XSL, you use `<xsl:comment>`:

```
<xsl:comment><![CDATA[[if IE 6]>
    Special instructions for IE 6 here
    <![endif]
    ]]>
</xsl:comment>
```

There is a specific reason why the CDATA follows the `<xsl:comment` on the same line here. IE does not recognize these comments unless the characters `<!--[if IE 6]>` are contiguous on a single line. The remaining portions, including the `endif`, can apparently be spread out onto succeeding lines.

However, since you cannot put an HTML comment in the middle of a tag, as you were trying to do. Therefore, you will have to provide alternate versions of the entire `<a>` tag:

```
<xsl:comment><![CDATA[[if IE 6]>
    <a title="hi" href="#">some text</a>
    <![endif]]]>
</xsl:comment>

<xsl:comment><![CDATA[[if gt IE 6]>
    <a href="#">some text</a>
    <![endif]]]>
</xsl:comment>
```

However, please note this [MS link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx):

> **Important**  As of Internet Explorer 10, conditional comments are no longer supported by standards mode.

#### Test output

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
    Special instructions for IE 6 here
    <![endif]
-->
```

Tested in IE9 emulation mode under IE11.

Comment: Tested. It does NOT work. <a <xsl:comment>[if IE 6]>Special instructions for IE 6 here<![endif]</xsl:comment> href="#">some text</a> To clarify, without it it works fine:  <a href="#">some text</a>

Comment: Sorry for the typos. Please check again.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you (if you use jQuery in your page) you include in IE comment a jquery external file that edit your A tag.

OR

You can set a xsl variable by some server side script (such as PHP) in order to discover browser type and make check test based on this variable.

Unfortunately XSLT is more depending by engine whom use, so you can use some special function based on engine, or use some other way.

Enjoy your code!